# laravel Eloquent/QueryBuilder - Why the value of variable $prod is become"?" in the Sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Sorry for my English grammar,..

I want to execute this query but is getting 0 result,..
i try to check in ->toSql() function i saw the value become ?,. instead of the value is "pork",.
why is become (?) question mark? and how to fix it?

this my laravel queries using model

```
$items = Item::where("item_type_id", "!=", 1)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($prod){
                    $query->where("description", "like", "'%$prod%'")
                    ->orWhere("id", "'%$prod%'");
            })
            ->toSql(); 
dd($items);
```

and the result is this, and the parameters become "?".

`` "select * from `items` where `item_type_id` != `` **?** `` and (`description` like ``**?**`` or `id` = ``**?**`)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**?** it's call Bindings used for SQL injection. if you want to get the bindings variable then you can use `getBindings()` method.

Check more detail of [getBindings()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getBindings)

```
$items = Item::where("item_type_id", "!=", 1)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($prod){
                    $query->where("description", "like", "'%$prod%'")
                    ->orWhere("id", "'%$prod%'");
            });

$sqlquery = $items->toSql(); 
$bindings = $items->getBindings();
```

Another way to replace **?** to value is below.

```
$sql_with_bindings = str_replace_array('?', $items->getBindings(), $items->toSql());
```

One more way to check the last executed query is `DB::enableQueryLog()`.

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$items = Item::where("item_type_id", "!=", 1)
              ->where(function ($query) use ($prod){
                   $query->where("description", "like", "'%$prod%'")
                         ->orWhere("id", "'%$prod%'");
                })->get();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Dilip 
 i got the result using enable the QuearyLog(),..

and i got this result,...


``array:1 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `items` where `item_type_id` <> ? and (`description` LIKE ? or `id` like ?)"
    "bindings" => array:3 [
      0 => 1
      1 => "%pork%"
      2 => "%pork%"
    ]
    "time" => 7.46
  ]
]``

Answer (score 1):

```
// Your code is Wrong. Please try this code
        $query = $request->input('query');
        $items = Item::where('description','LIKE',"%$query%",)->get();
```

Comment: thanks so much @Md.Azizur ,.. you are right! you fix my code,.. it is `" %$prod% "` not this`" '%$prod%' "`,.. and i got the result,..  but @Dilip got exact answer this post question,. sorry i will check his answer,.... thank you so much bro.//